# Dynamically draw a winline in Windows Forms Project

Tags: c#, line-drawing

so this is a TicTacToe game where the size of the button grid changes by being set in App.config. This is my `CheckXWinner` function that if X wins, it highlights the winning row combo and turns the buttons red. I want to add a dynamic line drawing that would be drawn from the start of the win pattern to the end (a line through the winning combo). On MSDN, it says to add the reference for Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.VS and `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks;` and then the following is their example for the code to draw the line:

```
ShapeContainer canvas = new ShapeContainer();
LineShape theLine = new LineShape();
// Set the form as the parent of the ShapeContainer.
canvas.Parent = this;
// Set the ShapeContainer as the parent of the LineShape.
theLine.Parent = canvas;
// Set the starting and ending coordinates for the line.
theLine.StartPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
theLine.EndPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(640, 480);
```

Here is my code for the `CheckXWinner` function:

```
public void CheckXWinner(Button[] buttonArray)
    {

        int arrLength = buttonArray.Length; 
        int root = (int)Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(arrLength));
        bool winner = false;//variable to keep the computer from going when Xwins
        for (int i = 0;  i < root;  i++)
        {
            //Sets the counter for the winners back to zero
            int d2Count = 0;
            int d1Count = 0;
            int hCount = 0;
            int vCount = 0;

                for(int j = 0;  j < root; j++)
                {
                    //increments the appropriate counter if the button contains an X
                    //Horizonal win
                    if (buttonArray[(i*root) + j].Text == "X")
                    {
                        hCount++;
                        if (hCount == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[(i*root) + z].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                            winner = true; //sets winner to true so computer does not take turn 
                        }
                    }//end of Horizonal win

                    //Left to right diagonal
                    if (buttonArray[j + (j*root)].Text == "X")
                    {
                        d1Count++;
                        if (d1Count == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[z + (z * root)].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                            winner = true; 
                        }
                    }//end of LTR win

                    //Right to left diagonal
                    if (buttonArray[(j*(root - 1)) + (root - 1)].Text == "X")
                    {
                        d2Count++;
                        if (d2Count == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[(z*(root - 1)) + (root - 1)].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                            winner = true; 
                        }
                    }//end of RTL win

                    //Vertical win
                    if (buttonArray[i + (root*j)].Text == "X")
                    {
                        vCount++;
                        if (vCount == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[i + (root*z)].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                            winner = true; 
                        }
                    }//end of vert win                        
                }//end of for j loop
        }//end of for loop
        CheckDraw();
        if (winner == false)
        {
            ComputerGoes(buttonArray);
        };

    }//end of CheckXWinner
```

How do I get the reference to my Form for the code for the line drawing? After that I would just call the points to be in the loop for turning the winning lines red. Thanks!